C++ template cannot call function with pointer parameter
I am new to C++. I am trying to implement AVLSearchTree with templates.
I have a template like this, specifically with an insert() public function, not posting the whole template here:
struct WordItem {
    string word;
    vector<DocumentItem> documents;
    WordItem(string w, string docName,int &c )
    {
        word = w;
        DocumentItem doc(docName,c);
        documents.push_back(doc);
    }
};

template <class Key, class Value>
    class AVLSearchTree
    {
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Node* left;
            Node* right;
            int height;
            Key key;
            Value value;
            Node(const Key&k, const Value& v)
                : key(k), value(v), height(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
        };
       
        Node* root;

        void insertin(Node*& t, const Key& k, const Value& v)
        {
            if (t == NULL)
            {
                t = new Node(k, v);
            }
            else if (k < t->key)
            {
                // Inserted into left tree
                insert(t->left, k, v);
                if (height(t->left) - height(t->right) == 2)
                {
                    if (k < t->left->key) // k was inserted to the left-left subtree
                        rotateWithLeftChild(t);
                    else
                        doubleWithLeftChild(t);
                }
            }
            else if (k > t->key)
            {
                // Inserted into right tree
                insert(t->right, k, v);
                if (height(t->right) - height(t->left) == 2)
                {
                    if (k > t->right->key)
                        rotateWithRightChild(t);// k was inserted to the right-right subtree
                    else
                        doubleWithRightChild(t);
                }
            }
            //update the height of the node
            t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right)) + 1;
        }
    public:
        AVLSearchTree() : root(NULL) {}
        ~AVLSearchTree()
        {
            makeEmpty(root);
        }
       
        void insert(Key& key, Value& value)
        {
            insertin(root, key, value);
        }

As I initiate my structure and try to call the insert() function like this:
AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem *> myTree;
    
string s = "someword";
string filename = "a.txt";
int initToOne = 1;
//WordItem* item = &WordItem(s, filename, initToOne);
WordItem* item(string s, string filename, int initToOne);
myTree.insert(s,  item);

I get an error:

error: cannot convert ‘WordItem*(std::string, std::string, int)’ {aka ‘WordItem*(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::__cxx11::basic_string, int)’} to ‘WordItem*&’

I tried almost each possibility, why does this happen? How can I fix this?

OT: Why do you pass c as a reference to the WordItem constructor? That makes no sense. What would make sense would be to pass the strings as (constant) references though. I also suggest you find the sections about constructor initializer lists in your beginners books or tutorials.

There is no syntax to write code that calls a constructor directly or forming a function pointer to it.

You can't take the address of a constructor, which is why this statement doesn't work:
&WordItem(s, filename, initToOne)
Your AVLSearchTree is expecting a pointer to a WordItem object. But this statement:
WordItem* item(string s, string filename, int initToOne);
is NOT an object declaration, it is a function declaration.  That is what the error message is complaining about - you are trying to insert a function pointer where an object pointer is expected.  You are declaring a function named item() that takes 3 parameters and returns a WordItem*.
But that is not what you want.  You need to instead declare an object instead, and then pass its address to insert(), eg:
AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem *> myTree;

string s = "someword";
string filename = "a.txt";
int initToOne = 1;

WordItem item(s, filename, initToOne);
myTree.insert(s, &item);

Just make sure that item lives longer than myTree needs it, otherwise you will leave myTree holding a dangling pointer when item gets destroyed while myTree is still pointing at it.
To avoid that, you can create item using new, and then delete it when myTree doesn't need it anymore.  If you change myTree to hold std::unique_ptr<WordItem> instead of WordItem*, that delete can be handled automatically for you.

The statement
WordItem* item(string s, string filename, int initToOne);

declares a function.
If you need  pointer you can use the pointer-to operator &:
WordItem item(s, filename, initToOne);
myTree.insert(s,  &item);

But only if the life-time of item is guaranteed to last as long as myTree.
You could also use dynamic allocation:
myTree.insert(s, new WordItem(s, filename, initToOne));

But then you have to remember to delete the elements.
Or, which is the more sane solution in my opinion, don't use pointers at all. Store WordItem objects, not pointers:
AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem> myTree;
myTree.insert(s, WordItem(s, filename, initToOne));


If you really need to use pointers, due to requirements, then I suggest using a smart pointer like std::unique_ptr.

I don't want to mess with functions of the structure, yet now I get the error, cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘WordItem*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘WordItem*’
thank you for your time!

@Tufan Change void insert(Key& key, Value& value) to void insert(const Key& key, const Value& value). Update the rest of the class as needed.
